# PHP : algorithm to get set of values from array

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I have a array with 2500 elements..I want simple algorithm to get the following.

If the input is 1 , then it should return 1st 50 elements.
If the input is 2 it should return 51 to 100th element.
if input is 3 it should return 101 to 150th element.

I am too much confused with this algorithm and my mind is not giving any idea,Some one please help me.

Note: i am coding my own pagination for 2500 url..And i need just algorithm idea..not coding

Comment: `array_slice($arr,($n-1)*50,50)` could be a starting point.

Comment: Why don't you search for a pagination tutorial and understand how it's done?

Comment: @blo i did and what tutorial teached was based on sql ...but i have list of url in a text file and i have converted to array.

Comment: @user2728612 you can count and select the desired amount of lines from a text file, now try google/read manual how to do it, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $ar = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30];

    function return_frame($arr, $multiplier, $frame_size=50, $preserve_keys = false) {
        return array_slice($arr, ($multiplier - 1)*$frame_size, $frame_size, $preserve_keys);

    }

    print_r(return_frame($ar, 2, 15, false));
?>

Array
(
    [0] => 16
    [1] => 17
    [2] => 18
    [3] => 19
    [4] => 20
    [5] => 21
    [6] => 22
    [7] => 23
    [8] => 24
    [9] => 25
    [10] => 26
    [11] => 27
    [12] => 28
    [13] => 29
    [14] => 30
)
```

Take a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Answer (score 0):

i think you just can add position and range on your sql code like this :

```
"select * from blabla order by post desc limit $position,$range"
```

Comment: Its not sql ,,i have list of url in text file

Comment: actually, you want to get result 1 to 50 when you input number 1 right, so in the logic, you just need to put a range(1 to 50) in the some position(your input : 1 or etc)

Answer (score 0):

You have indexes from 0 to 2499 right.

you want a **$count** of **50**. 
Let me show you the thinking process.

so if you get **1** as a `$paramter` you want `$start` to be 0 and `$end` to be 49.

lets see:

`1-$parameter` is $start right. and `50-$paramter` is $end . ok

for 2 you want $start to be 50 and $end to be 99;

**the above does not work here. lets play with the `$count`**

`$parameter*count;` is almost $end.. we have to play for the **0 indexing**. so:

`$end` will be `$parameter*$count-1`. we can see that this is true for 1,2 and also 3 as `$parameters`.
`$start` will be `($parameter-1)*$count` . just quickly in the head that gives **0,50,100**. just what we want.

as  @cars10 suggested we do not need the `$end`. with `array_slice($arr,($parameter-1)*$count,$count);`